# My function is too long and I'm told to optimize

Tags: python

So I'm doing a project for an online class and when i got it scored it came back as not passed because my "play game" function was more than 18 lines long and I'm supposed to optimize it. The problem is they didn't make any suggestions as to what i should do and I keep looking at it and feel as if I need everything in it to make the fill in the blank quiz I'm building work. Any suggestions would be great as I am still very new to coding, and maybe what they are asking me to do is easy and I'm over complicating it in my head. This is the part of the code they want optimized...

```
def play():
    '''
    This is the main function which allows to play the game/quiz.
    It calls the previous functions we have written.
    '''
    quiz = difficulty_level(user_level)         #gives the difficulty 
paragraph that the user asks for.
    print quiz
    print "\nYou will get maximum 3 guesses for each blank. Good luck.\n"
    answers_list = relate_answer(user_level)    #makes sure that the right 
list is called up
    blanks_index = 0
    answers_index = 0
    number_of_guesses = 3

    while blanks_index < len(blanks):   #This loop keeps going if all the 
blanks are not replaced.
        user_answer = raw_input("type in your answer for " + blanks[blanks_index] + ": ")
        if check_answer(user_answer,answers_list,answers_index) == "Correct":
            print "Awesome job! You gave the right answer!\n"
            quiz = quiz. replace(blanks[blanks_index],user_answer)
            blanks_index += 1
            answers_index += 1
            number_of_guesses = 3
            print quiz
        else:
            number_of_guesses -= 1
            if number_of_guesses == 0:
                print "Game over! But try again!"
                break
            elif number_of_guesses < 0:
                print "invalid"
                break
            else:
                print "please try again."
                print "You have " + str(number_of_guesses) + " guesses left."

    print "Congratulations! You really know your stuff!."

play()
```

Comment: Optimize or shorten?

Comment: better to ask this in code review stack exchange forum

Comment: One thing you can easily do is implement some [tuple assignments/unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). e.g. `blanks_index, answers_index, number_of_guesses = 0, 0, 3`

Comment: Also, you can bring your `break` statements into the `while` check by adding `and number_of_guesses > 0` to the `while` statement.

Comment: Split it up into smaller functions

Comment: Combine `print` statements, e.g., `print ("please try again.\nYou have {} guesses left.".format(number_of_guesses))`

Comment: for optimization, add function parameters `user_level`, `blanks`...look-up for these variables will be faster if you pass them as arguments, last but not least it increases transparency on what variables your function depends on if you pass them as arguments.

Comment: If the objective is simply to be as short as possible without concern for readability, you can consolidate the print and conditional statements using [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick summation of changes:

It looks like `answers_index` and `blanks_index` share the same state, no matter what, so we can generalize that to one variable `idx`. That cuts down on the number of variables you have to keep track of.

As others have suggested, initializing variables as a tuple like `var1, var2 = 1, 2` decreases length and makes code more readable (to a point). If you have lots of variables to initialize, you can break the initialization into groups of related variables.

Setting a default value to `user_level` increases readability, and also gives an easy place to start debugging your function. This occurs in the `def` statement, so if you don't pass the argument, `user_level` will be `1`, otherwise it will be whatever you give it in the function call. Example `play(user_level=40)` will overwrite that default value.

Putting the game loss condition at the start of the `while` loop increases visibility of the checks the code goes through before executing anything unnecessary. This should help you avoid the case where `guess` would be less than `0`, because that code won't execute when `guess==0` is `True`.

Setting a `lose` boolean with the check after exiting the `while` loop will also prevent the wrong `print` statement at the end from executing. That way, if the player loses, you will print the proper message.

Breaking the update of `quiz` into another function adds a more compact breakpoint into the code. In general, smaller functions that do less are preferable to large functions that do a lot. The smallest number of changes necessary is a good standard for what should be wrapped into a function, though this could be considered a stylistic convention more than a hard and fast rule.

The `correct_answer` method allows you to update `quiz` and `guess` in one line, and if something is wrong with the update itself, you don't have to run the entire script over and over. Instead you can take the `quiz` that might be causing the problem and plug it into that function until you find what's causing the problem.

I've made some minimal updates to the function you've provided which keep most of your conventions so far. Hopefully this is helpful, and happy coding!

```
def correct_answer(quiz, blank, answer):
    """
    Function to update the quiz and return
    both the quiz and reset guess to 3
    """
    print("Awesome job! You gave the right answer!\n")
    quiz = quiz.replace(blank, answer)
    return quiz, 3

def play(user_level=1):
    '''
    This is the main function which allows to play the game/quiz.
    It calls the previous functions we have written.
    '''

    idx, guess, lose = 0, 3, False

    quiz = difficulty_level(user_level)         #gives the difficulty paragraph that the user asks for.
    print(quiz)
    print("\nYou will get maximum 3 guesses for each blank. Good luck.\n")
    answers_list = relate_answer(user_level)    #makes sure that the right list is called up

    while idx < len(blanks):   #This loop keeps going if all the blanks are not replaced.

        if guess <= 0:
            lose = True
            break

        user_answer = raw_input("type in your answer for %s:" %str(blanks[idx]))

        if check_answer(user_answer,answers_list,idx) == "Correct":
            quiz, guess = correct_answer(quiz, blanks[idx], user_answer)
            print(quiz)

        else:
            guess -= 1
            print("please try again.\nYou have %s guesses left.\n"%str(guess))
        idx += 1
    if lose:
       print("Game over, try again")
    else:
       print("Congratulations! You really know your stuff!.")

play(user_level = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!